# Implement Read More feature for multiple textual children in React

Tags: reactjs

I have seen multiple `npm` packages that do it with a single textual child component, but none of them seems to support multiple textual children.

For example, I want to implement a Read More/Read Less to a component that has 2 `<p />` as children:

```
function ReadMoreComponent (props) {
  return (
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  )
}
```

If `Paragraph 1` is long enough, `ReadMoreComponent` would render the `Paragraph 1` partially and show the Read More button. In case `Paragraph 1` is shorter than the limit, `ReadMoreComponent` would show the entire `Paragraph 1` and part of `Paragraph 2` before showing the Read More button.

Is it possible to implement a Read More/Read Less feature on a React Component that has multiple textual children?

Comment: Not familiar with the packages personally, but have you tried just using a `<Fragment />` with those packages? Because that is the only way to return adjacent JSX elements anway.

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe something like this would. A <Text /> component is a <Fragment /> wrapping over some paragraph elements. We need to make a higher-order component <ReadMoreWrapper /> that wraps that Text component and adds that functionality. It would need to access props.children to access the Fragment, then iterating over the paragraphs in that Fragment’s children until some hard-coded max length is reached. When/if that happens, we select everything up to the last paragraph and add the “Read More” text.

Comment: Whether the entire text is opened or shut can just depend on one stateful variable in the HOC, state = { isReadMoreOn: true } etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do something like this.
Add some function which can make short version of your children components:

```
function short(arr, maxLen){
    let l=0;
    for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (l+arr[i].props.children.length > maxLen) {
              let res = arr.slice(0,i);
                let partial = arr[i].props.children.substring(0,maxLen-l)
                res.push((<p>{partial}</p>))
                return res;
            }
        l = l+arr[i].props.children.length;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Create your React component and use its state to turn short/long mode:

```
function ReadMoreComponent (props) {
    const [shortMode, setShortMode] = useState(true);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {shortMode ? (<React.Fragment>{short(props.children, 25)}</React.Fragment>) : props.children}
      <button onClick={() => setShortMode(!shortMode)}>{shortMode ? 'full' : 'short'}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Use your component:

```
<ReadMoreComponent>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <p>Paragraph 4</p>
</ReadMoreComponent>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is really straight forward, don't know why I didn't think of it before asking. It still doesn't work for my use, as my `<p />` doesn't have only text inside, having multiple `<span />` and media tags, but it already a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want a component that accepts HTML elements (as react elements) and not just a string, and then truncates the final text to be displayed according to a limit you specify.

You can parse the input, access the children of the elements until you reach a string, then count the amount of chars in the string, truncating and stopping the process after the maximum amount of chars is reached.

The following is an example of a component to do that:

```tsx
import React from 'react';

type ParseResult = {
    content: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    remaining: number;
};

type Parse = (root: ParseResult, parse: Parse) => ParseResult;

const parseString = (text: string, remaining: number): ParseResult => {
    if (!text?.length) {
        return { content: text, remaining };
    }

    const newText =
        remaining <= 0
            ? ''
            : text.length > remaining
            ? text.substring(0, remaining)
            : text;

    return { content: newText, remaining: remaining - text.length };
};

const parse: Parse = (root, parseCallback) => {
    const { content, remaining = 0 } = root;

    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        const result = parseString(content, remaining);
        return result;
    } else if (React.isValidElement(content)) {
        const children = (content.props as { children?: React.ReactNode })
            ?.children;

        if (children != null) {
            const innerResult = parseCallback(
                {
                    content: children,
                    remaining,
                },
                parseCallback,
            );
            const newContent = React.cloneElement(content, {}, innerResult.content);
            return { content: newContent, remaining: innerResult.remaining };
        }
    } else if (Array.isArray(content)) {
        const list: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        let newRemaining = remaining;

        for (const child of content) {
            const parsed = parseCallback(
                { content: child, remaining: newRemaining },
                parseCallback,
            );
            newRemaining = parsed.remaining;
            const newContent = (
                <React.Fragment key={list.length}>{parsed.content}</React.Fragment>
            );
            list.push(newContent);

            if (newRemaining < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return { content: list, remaining: newRemaining };
    }

    return root;
};

export interface ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    expanded?: boolean;
    showMore?: React.ReactNode;
    showLess?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ReadMoreInner: React.FC<
    {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        truncate: number;
    } & ReadMoreAdditionalProps
> = ({ truncate, expanded, showMore, showLess, children }) => {
    const root: ParseResult = {
        content: children,
        remaining: truncate,
    };
    const result = parse(root, parse);

    return (
        <>
            {expanded ? children : result.content}
            {result.remaining < 0 ? (expanded ? showLess : showMore) : undefined}
        </>
    );
};

export interface ReadMoreOptions extends ReadMoreAdditionalProps {
    truncate?: number;
}

export type ReadMoreProps = ReadMoreOptions & {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const ReadMore: React.FC<ReadMoreProps> = ({
    truncate,
    children,
    ...props
}) => {
    return truncate != null ? (
        <ReadMoreInner {...props} truncate={truncate}>
            {children}
        </ReadMoreInner>
    ) : (
        <>{children}</>
    );
};
```

Keep in mind that this component expects the children components to contain the final text (or no text). It won't access other properties (like a `text` or `title` property), but that should be fine for HTML components.

The above component itself is not bound by HTML and require no other libraries than react, so it can be used in react native too.

You can just include this component in your code, add buttons to show more or less text and then style the buttons the way you want.

I created a library to do this and an easily customizable web component if you prefer to not add all the component code in your project.

Install the library with:

```tsx
npm install react-shorten
```

Below is an example of how to use the library:

```tsx
import { ReadMoreWeb } from 'react-shorten';
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent: React.FC<{
    truncate?: number;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ truncate, children }) => (
    <ReadMoreWeb
        truncate={20}
        showMoreText="Show more"
        showLessText="Show less"
        className="read-more-btn"
    >
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
        <p>Paragraph 4</p>
        <p>Paragraph 5</p>
        <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        <p>Paragraph 7</p>
    </ReadMoreWeb>
);
```

with the css:

```css
.read-more-btn {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: rgb(80, 154, 223);
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link {
    color: rgb(26, 210, 243);
}
```

You can see a web demo [here](https://lucasbasquerotto.github.io/react-read-more/) and a native demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lucasbasquerotto/react-shorten).

You can also use the demos as references and include the [ReadMore](https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/react-read-more/blob/main/src/components/read-more.tsx) and [ReadMoreWeb](https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/react-read-more/blob/main/src/components/read-more-web.tsx) components directly in your project, if you prefer to not install another library.